# Error when compiling twitterbootstrap buttons.less on WinLess

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I get an 'eval' is null or not object on WinLess on buttons.less.

Anyone ?

ps. I have used the latest version of everything and import variables / mixins

the version I used are:
WinLess 1.5.3
Less 1.3
Bootstrap 2.04

**Edit:**

This is fixed in Bootstrap 2.1.1

Comment: Please, could you provide more information about the version of your softwares: bootstrap, WinLess, less, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twitter bootstrap team [states](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3894) that they do not guarantee compilation of individual files like button.less. They encourage the compilation of the bootstrap.less which has all the needed dependencies. Otherwise you have to be sure that you have all the dependencies needed by button.less (usually mixins.less and variables.less).

Actually the problem seems to be related to some parsing problems in WinLess, so before it is fixed you can come around with a hack which will dupe the WinLess parser. In mixins.less, change :

```
// IE7 inline-block
// ----------------
.ie7-inline-block() {
  *display: inline; /* IE7 inline-block hack */
  *zoom: 1;
}
```

with :

```
// IE7 inline-block
// ----------------
.ie7-inline-block() {
  *display: inline; /* IE7 inline-block hack */
  *zoom: 1;
  // comment to make it work with WinLESS
}
```

As you can see it consists to the adding a new line to **`// comment to make it work with WinLESS`** to dupe the WinLess parser and make it work!

Comment: like I said. I have import variables / mixins. Actually if you try bootstrap.less with winless, you get this error as well.

Comment: Very cool ! it does work. I came out another work around as well.

Comment: maybe we should send this post to the author of winless.

Comment: As far as I know, the WinLess team seems to be aware of the bug (there a several issues opened about this bug on GitHub) and it will be fixed  in future releases.

Answer (score 0):

There is another work around.

Remove the comments in button.less at

```
    .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  .ie7-inline-block();
  padding: 4px 10px 4px;
  margin-bottom: 0; // For input.btn
  font-size: @baseFontSize;
  line-height: @baseLineHeight;
  *line-height: 20px;
  color: @grayDark;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.75);
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  .buttonBackground(@btnBackground, @btnBackgroundHighlight);
  border: 1px solid @btnBorder;
  *border: 0; **// Remove the border to prevent IE7's black border on input:focus  [remove this]**
  border-bottom-color: darken(@btnBorder, 10%);
  .border-radius(4px);
  .ie7-restore-left-whitespace(); **// Give IE7 some love [remove this]**
  .box-shadow(~"inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05)");
}
```