# LESS (client side) does not compile certain CSS properties

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, browser, less

The website I'm working on need to support IE7 and `display: inline-block` does not work there.

From searching around I see that `*display: inline;` and `*zoom: 1;` can solve this problem. The problem is that this does not show up in my compiled CSS with LESS.

Even `zoom: 1;` does not compile (without star symbol). To be sure I added some other valid property to the same CSS class and that works.

In summary: I can't get `zoom` and IE7 CSS-property selector (*) to work with LESS in my browser. Any fix to this?

```
<script>less = {env: 'development'};<script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what compiler you are using. You might check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285295/error-when-compiling-twitterbootstrap-buttons-less-on-winless/11285444#11285444 for a possible solution. On  the http://less2css.org/ compiler, I have no issues as you show, so it seems to be a compiler specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

With LESS 1.5

```
// IE7 inline-block
// ----------------
.ie7-inline-block() {
  *display: inline; /* IE7 inline-block hack */
  *zoom: 1;
}

p{
.ie7-inline-block();
}
```

compile to:

```
p {
  *display: inline;
  /* IE7 inline-block hack */
  *zoom: 1;
}
```